# How do I implement functions with native code in Ionic 2?

Tags: android, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, background-service

I'm writing an Android application as well as I would like to create a background `Service` for my Ionic 2 application. However, it seems that it's impossible to create a background `Service`  using TypeScript. So I would like to write a background `Service` in native Java.

The problem is where should I write my native code and how would I interact with my TypeScript?

Comment: Just to give you some pointers. When you start a new Ionic app it also has PhoneGap included. PhoneGap is what gives you the bridge between JavaScript and native code (in your case Java). What you need to do is create a PhoneGap plugin that achieves your desired functionality. Hopefully this link will help you out http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-how-to-write-a-phonegap-plugin-for-android/

Comment: @Will.Harris In fact, ionic implements our app with Webview, doesn't it? So that we should actually build a bridge between native and webview, shouldn't we?

Comment: I may be wrong but I think it is PhoneGap that loads the app into a webview, Ionic is just the CSS that styles it inside the webview. So yes the bridge is between native and webview which can be achieved using PhoneGap plugins.

Comment: I am also facing almost similar problem i want to access Java API from IONIC app (which is using typescript) is there any solution for this ?